# can I use mlflow python API to register a spark UDF & then use the UDF in Spark scala code?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, mlflow

I'm trying to use mlflow to do the machine learning work. I register the ML model as UDF using the following python code. The question is how can I use the UDF(test_predict) in my scala code? The reason is that our main code is in Scala. The problem is that UDF created below is a temporary UDF and SparkSession scoped. thanks!

```py
import sys
import mlflow
from mlflow import pyfunc
import numpy as np
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sc=SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Python UDF example").getOrCreate()
pyfunc_udf=mlflow.pyfunc.spark_udf(spark=spark, model_uri="./sk",result_type="float")
spark.udf.register("test_predict",pyfunc_udf)
```

Comment: Python code in PySpark gets sent around in picked form by the driver and executes in external Python processes spawned by the executors. When the driver program is gone, so are the UDFs. Your best option is to have the driver written in Python and either have your Scala code as a set of UDFs or make use of the Py4J gateway through the (undocumented) `_jvm` member of the Spark context to call into Scala. See [here](https://aseigneurin.github.io/2016/09/01/spark-calling-scala-code-from-pyspark.html) on how to do the latter.

Comment: thanks. you're saying driver program is python and python code invokes scala code. I'm thinking of the reverse. i.e. scala code(driver program) invokes python code to register UDF before using.

Comment: I'm saying it will be easier if your driver is written in Python and calls into Scala than the other way round. Perhaps you can achieve the opposite somehow too using Py4J. The `SparkContext` constructor in PySpark accepts Java context objects, so it should be possible in principle to transfer the context. Same for `SparkSession`. It'll be interesting to see your solution once you have it working.

Comment: Please, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76802912/how-to-use-pyspark-udf-in-java-scala-spark-project